# Classroom API - CourseAlias

Tags: java, google-api

O seguinte código refere-se a criação de um curso pela API do Classroom. Porém a API não permite definir manualmente um 'ID' (usando .setId("ID")). Para isso é disponibilizada a criação de um Alias (único) para cada curso.

```
public void createCourse() throws 
{
    Course course = new Course()
            .setName(name)
            .setSection(alias+" - "+periodo.toUpperCase())
            .setDescriptionHeading(heading)
            .setDescription(desc)
            .setOwnerId(professor)
            .setEnrollmentCode(alias.toLowerCase())
            .setCourseState("ACTIVE");
    course = service.courses().create(course).execute();
    System.out.printf("Course created: %s (%s)\n", course.getName(), course.getId());

    CourseAlias courseAlias = new CourseAlias()
            .setAlias("Teste");
    courseAlias = service.courses().aliases().create(course.getId(), courseAlias)
            .execute();
    System.out.printf("Course alias: %s (%s)\n", "10820582852", courseAlias.getAlias());
}
```

O curso é criado sem problemas, mas quando a requisição para criação do alias me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad 
Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at management.Cursos.createCourse(Cursos.java:64)
    at client.LoadClassroom.main(LoadClassroom.java:108)
```

Comment: qual a url que você ta enviando a requisição?

Comment: O comando .execute() trabalha com as urls necessárias pra fazer os requests... Fiz basicamente como é demostrado na [API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/java), só alterei o escopo e umas configurações de acesso.

Comment: O escopo necessário pra essa operação é: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!
A String do alias tem uma configuração própria, a string deve iniciar com 'd:' que indica escopo de domínio ou 'p:' que indica escopo de projeto.

Antes eu tinha assim:

```
CourseAlias courseAlias = new CourseAlias()
        .setAlias("Teste");
```

mas o correto é:

```
CourseAlias courseAlias = new CourseAlias()
        .setAlias("d:Teste");
```